# How to make use of the default implementation of operator new when replacing it?

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

In C++, the global allocation/deallocation functions (`operator new` and `operator delete`) can be 'overloaded', while such overloading is actually **replacing** the original ones provided by the standard library. But sometimes I just want to do something, e.g. saving the address of the allocated memory block, or recording the memory usage, without caring about how the memory is allocated/deallocated.

Currently, my solution is to replace all these functions and use `malloc`/`free` for allocation/deallocation, and I have to 'imitate' the standard library behaviors like writing a loop and dealing with the `new_handler` stuff. It is really annoying - I have to replace the nothrow versions, the alignment-aware versions, the sized deallocations, etc.

Is there a way of adding something to the allocation/deallocation procedure without rewriting the whole thing? If there is no such way, why?

Comment: 1 No. 2 Nobody proposed it.

Comment: The default non-throwing versions call the corresponding throwing versions (and presumably catch any exception to return null) and the array versions call the non-array versions.   That means, you only need to replace the throwing non-array versions when you want to "do something" and you will implicitly have given the same "something" to the non-throwing and array versions.   So it's not "all or nothing" - you just need to be selective in picking which ones you replace, to ensure your added functionality is received by the ones you don't manually replace.

Comment: @Peter Why would the non-throwing versions call the throwing versions? It makes no sense at all when the system memory allocation procedure already returns NULL for error. In this case then the throwing version would check for NULL and throw, for the non-throwing version to catch and return NULL again. It makes much more sense for the non-throwing version to just return the result from the system procedure and then the throwing version checks the non-throwing result.

Comment: @Mestkon - They do it that way because that's what the standard says.    As to why - that comes down to a design decision made during the standardisation process.    They had to choose an order of things, and they did.

Comment: @Peter Well, if the standard explicitly says so. They picked the wrong order then IMO.

Comment: @Mestkon - You can always take it up by making a submission to the standardisation committee.   They'll probably require a fairly strong justification for the change though.   My guess is that the choice supports a lot of properties of the C++ standard library (exception safety guarantees of allocators and resizing operations on containers, among others) and changing that would require changing quite a few things (and possibly break code that relies on the way it is now).